# Visual Studio 2015 C# hotkey to collapse containing region

Tags: c#, visual-studio, region

I use lots of #region to organize my C# codes and one very-often thing I have to repeat is collapse and/or expand the `#region` area by clicking on the button lie at the `#region containing line` - i.e. the one marked with @1 as the below snapshot.

It would be lovely to be able to have a hotkey so that we can quickly collapse/expand the current region that contains the current line where the caret is in.

My [google search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=visual+studio+2015+c%23+hotkey+to+collapse+containing+region+that+wrap+the+current+line) comes up little helps so I ask here.

Is it possible and how can we archive that?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl+M, Ctrl+S is used to expand or collapse the current region

from [MSD](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/da5kh0wa.aspx)

Comment: Wel `Ctrl-M, S` just collapsing the current `code block` not the `#region block`. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

With visual studio defaults you can:

- Collapse current region <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>. Command `Edit.CollapseCurrentRegion`
- Expand current region <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>. Command `Edit.ExpandCurrentRegion`

Try to set it up or find out your settings for these commands in Options->Environment->Keyboard

Comment: Wel `Ctrl-M, S` just collapsing the current `code block` not the `#region block`. Thanks anyway.